# Upload .csv with FastAPI and JS fetch

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, csv, fastapi

My app uses React on the frontend and FastAPI on the backend.

I'm trying to upload a csv file to my server.

On submitting a form, this gets called:

```js
  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    fetch("/api/textitems/upload", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });
  };
```

The data is received by:

```py
@app.post('/api/textitems/upload')
def upload_file(csv_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_file.file)
    return dataframe.head()
```

I keep getting `INFO:     127.0.0.1:0 - "POST /api/textitems/upload HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity` errors.

I am able to successfully perform the post request with curl like so:

`curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/api/textitems/upload" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "csv_file=@exp_prod.csv;type=text/csv"`

Any advice about where I'm going wrong when using Javascript though?

Comment: Do you have `python-multipart` installed on your current environment?

Comment: Yes I do have `python-multipart`

Comment: I think your returning value causes this, by default fastapi expects key:value pairs, i'm not sure how `head()` sends data but can you try with dict? Also there was a function like `to_dict()` in pandas or something else and `FileResponse` from `fastapi.responses` could be helpful.

Comment: I've tried but unfortunately without success. I'm fairly sure it's that JS's fetch method is not sending something that FastAPI considers a correct type. I believe this because the endpoint does not even run when the input comes from my frontend yet  it returns the desired output when invoked using curl.

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655118/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71478057/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74588435/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71711008/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74810115/17865804)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did eventually solve this. Isabi's answer helped me, as did learning about [FormData's append method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append). Here are the working code snippets in case anyone finds them useful.

```js
  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file, file.name);
    await fetch(`/api/textitems/upload`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    })
```

```py
@app.post('/api/textitems/upload')
def upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    df = pd.read_csv(file.file).head()
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the name of the file in the form matches the name of the file in the parameter!

See my answer to the same question below.

[How to send file to fastapi endpoint using postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62798421/how-to-send-file-to-fastapi-endpoint-using-postman#comment111071496_62798421)

Answer (score 1):

@henry-dashwood's answer worked for me, but I had to modify it a bit to get it to work in SvelteKit:

```ts
import { env } from '$env/dynamic/private';

/** @type {import('./$types').Actions} */
export const actions: import('./$types').Actions = {
    uploadFile: async ({ request }) => {

        // Get the form data
        const formData = await request.formData();
        const file = formData.get('fileToUpload') as File; // taken from the `name` field on the form
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);

        await fetch(`${env.BACKEND_URL}/pdf-upload/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => console.log(data))
            .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error));

        return {
            success: true
        };


    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Content-Type header to `multipart/form-data` on your request:

```js
  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    fetch("/api/textitems/upload", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      }
    });
  };
```