# How to send a base64 encoded image to a FastAPI backend?

Tags: javascript, python, base64, fastapi

I'm using code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064793/1445531) and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285053/1445531) to send a base64 encoded image to a python FastAPI backend.

The **client side** looks like this:

```js
function toDataURL(src, callback, outputFormat) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
            img.onload = function() {
                var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var dataURL;
                canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
                canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
                ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
                callback(dataURL);
            };
            img.src = src;
            if (img.complete || img.complete === undefined) {
                img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";
                img.src = src;
            }
        }

        function makeBlob(dataURL) {
            var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
            if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
                var parts = dataURL.split(',');
                var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
                var raw = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
                return new Blob([raw], { type: contentType });
            }
            var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
            var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
            var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
            var rawLength = raw.length;

            var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

            for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
                uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType });
        }

        ...

        toDataURL(
            images[0], // images is an array of paths to images
            function(dataUrl) {
                console.log('RESULT:', dataUrl);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://0.0.0.0:8000/check/",
                    type: 'POST',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
                    data: makeBlob(dataUrl)
                }).done(function(data) {console.log("success");}).fail(function() {console.log("error");});
            }
        );
```

And the **server side** is as follows:

```
@app.post("/check")
async def check(file: bytes = File(...)) -> Any:  
    // do something here
```

I'm only showing the signature of the endpoint because for now nothing much is happening in it anyway.

Here is the output of the backend when I call it as shown above:

> 172.17.0.1:36464 - "OPTIONS /check/ HTTP/1.1" 200
>
> 172.17.0.1:36464 - "POST /check/ HTTP/1.1" 307
>
> 172.17.0.1:36464 - "OPTIONS /check HTTP/1.1" 200
>
> 172.17.0.1:36464 - "POST /check HTTP/1.1" 422

So, in short, I keep getting `422 error` codes, which means that there is a mismatch between what I send and what the endpoint expects, but even after some reading I'm still not clear on what exactly is the issue. Any help would be most welcome!

Comment: For fault isolation: What happens when you use the buffer of your TypedArray rather than the TypedArray itself? Like this: `new Blob(uInt8Array.buffer, { type: contentType });` rather than this `new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType });`

Comment: Have you tried with `UploadFile` as a type for your file parameter? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/?h=+file#file-parameters-with-uploadfile

Comment: @RandyCasburn if I try that I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Blob constructor: Argument 1 can't be converted to a sequence.` 
@lsabi yes I tried that too, exact same behavior! Makes me think that whatever my Javascript sends is not recognized as either a file nor even a proper bytestream, does it make sense?

Comment: I am unable to recreate the issue using your exact code with a known good image. Most likely cause is a corrupted image located on your server or an image path that points to a non-image file (like a text file masquerading as an image).

Comment: In other words, your code works correctly as written (even though you don't provide. third argument to `toDataURL()` and use the `undefined` third parameter directly in your code.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804), uploaded files are sent as `form` data. As per [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/):

> Data from forms is normally encoded using the "media type"
> `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when it doesn't include files.
>
> But **when the form includes files, it is encoded as**
> `multipart/form-data`. If you use `File`, FastAPI will know it has to get
> the files from the correct part of the body.

Regardless of what type you used, either `bytes` or `UploadFile`, since...

> If you declare the type of your path operation function parameter as
> `bytes`, **FastAPI will read the file for you** and you will receive the
> contents as bytes.

Hence, the `422 Unprocessable entity` error. In your example, you send binary data (using `application/octet-stream` for `content-type`), however, your API's endpoint expects `form` data (i.e., `multipart/form-data`).

### Option 1

Instead of sending a base64 encoded image, upload the `file` as is, either using an HTML `form`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804), or Javascript, as shown below. As others pointed out, [it is imperative that you set the contentType option to false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031), when using JQuery. Using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), as shown below, it is best to leave it out as well, and force the browser to set it (along with the mandatory [multipart boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data)). For `async` read/write in the FastAPI backend, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804).

**app.py**:

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import File, UploadFile, Request, FastAPI
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        contents = file.file.read()
        with open("uploaded_" + file.filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(contents)
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
    finally:
        file.file.close()
        
    return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {file.filename}"}

@app.get("/")
def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<script>
function uploadFile(){
    var file = document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0];
    if(file){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        fetch('/upload', {
               method: 'POST',
               body: formData,
             })
             .then(response => {
               console.log(response);
             })
             .catch(error => {
               console.error(error);
             });
    }
}
</script>
<input type="file" id="fileInput" name="file"><br>
<input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
```

If you would like to use `Axios`library for the upload, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70824288/17865804).

### Option 2

If you still need to upload a base64 encoded image, you can send the data as `form` data, using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the `content-type`; while in your API's endpoint, you can define a [`Form`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/) field to receive the data. Below is a complete working example, where a base64 encoded image is sent, received by the server, decoded and saved to the disk. For base64 encoding, the [readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) method is used on client side. Please note, the file writing to the disk is done using synchronous writing. In scenarios where multiple (or large) files need to be saved, it would be best to use `async` writing, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804).

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import Form, Request, FastAPI
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import base64

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(filename: str = Form(...), filedata: str = Form(...)):
    image_as_bytes = str.encode(filedata)  # convert string to bytes
    img_recovered = base64.b64decode(image_as_bytes)  # decode base64string
    with open("uploaded_" + filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(img_recovered)
    return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {filename}"}

@app.get("/")
def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function previewFile() {
        const preview = document.querySelector('img');
        const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("load", function () { 
            preview.src = reader.result; //show image in <img tag>
            base64String = reader.result.replace("data:", "").replace(/^.+,/, "");
            uploadFile(file.name, base64String)
        }, false);

        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
    function uploadFile(filename, filedata){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("filename", filename);
        formData.append("filedata", filedata);
         fetch('/upload', {
               method: 'POST',
               body: formData,
             })
             .then(response => {
               console.log(response);
             })
             .catch(error => {
               console.error(error);
             });
      }

</script>
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```