# How do you pass in an image through a template and use a model to predict with FastAPI?

Tags: python, api, tensorflow, keras, fastapi

I am trying to create a machine learning web application. I have an html page that takes in an image (jpg or png) and I am loading my model into the API to predict on the image and output results. The lines under the prediction function of FastAPI have worked in a separate file but I think something is wrong with the data format that is taken in by the API.

```
from starlette.responses import RedirectResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form
from tensorflow.keras import preprocessing
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/Templates", StaticFiles(directory="Templates"), name="Templates")

model_dir = 'F:\\Saved-Models\\Dog-Cat-Models\\First_Generation_dog_cat_optuna.h5'
model = load_model(model_dir)


@app.get('/')
async def index():
    return RedirectResponse(url="/Templates/index.html")


@app.post('/prediction_page')
async def prediction_form(dogcat_img: bytes = Form(...)):
    pp_dogcat_image = preprocessing.image.load_img(dogcat_img, target_size=(150, 150))
    pp_dogcat_image_arr = preprocessing.image.img_to_array(pp_dogcat_image)
    input_arr = np.array([pp_dogcat_image_arr])
    prediction = np.argmax(model.predict(input_arr), axis=-1)
    print(prediction)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='localhost', port=8000)
```

The error I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'cat.83.jpg'
```

It shouldn't need a full path because the image is getting passed through the webpage right? I have also tried UploadFile instead of bytes and got this error:

```
INFO:     ::1:6918 - "POST /prediction_page HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

Edit:
HTML Code:

```
<form action="/prediction_page" method="post">
        <label for="image-upload" class="custom-file-upload">Select Image:</label>
        <input type="file" id="image-upload" name="dogcat_img"><br>
        <input class="custom-submit-button" type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send a base64 encoded image to a FastAPI backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788970/how-to-send-a-base64-encoded-image-to-a-fastapi-backend)

Answer (score 0):

Use `async def prediction_form(dogcat_img: bytes = File(...)):`
if you want to get bytes data.

In your case:
`pp_dogcat_image = preprocessing.image.load_img(dogcat_img, target_size=(150, 150))` seem this line will load a file from local file path. So i suggest you use `UploadFile` type instead of bytes.
And your function be like:

```py
# ...
from fastapi import File, UploadFile
# ...

async def prediction_form(dogcat_img: UploadFile = File(...)):
    # ...
    pp_dogcat_image = preprocessing.image.load_img(dogcat_img.file_name, target_size=(150, 150))
```

Comment: So I actually tried that before and it gave me this error: INFO:     ::1:6918 - "POST /prediction_page HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity. I tried to look in the swagger UI for something useful but nada

Comment: If you're testing on swagger UI so the request content type should be `multipart/form-data` as expected. Try `async def prediction_form(*, dogcat_img: UploadFile = File(...)):`

Comment: Yeah tried that, still getting un-processable entity...