# FastAPI POST - Error 422 detail'': ( ( loc'':(body file msg'':field required'', type'': value_error missing)))

Tags: python, typescript, forms, post, fastapi

I want to read in backend this xlsx file. When I use the swagger I get it, but when I test in frontend I receive an Error 422 - devtools/Network detail'': ( ( loc'':(body file msg'':field required'', type'': value_error missing))).

```
router = APIRouter()

@router.post('/')
async def upload_file(file: Uploadfile = File(...)):

  try:
    arquivo = await file.read()
    df_cambio = pd.read_excel(arquivo)
    cambio_dict = df_cambio.to_dict('index')
    
    print(cambio_dict)
    return{"file_name": file.filename}
  
  except Exception as e:
    exception_handler(e)
```

react ->

```
export defaut function Dropzone() {
const [create, {isLoading}] = usePost();

const handleSubmit = (res) => {
    create('cambios', { data:res.file }})
};
if (isLoading) { return <LoadingPageSkeleton />;}

return (

<BasicForm
  initialValues={{}}
  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
>
    <FormInput id="file />
    <FormSubmitButton/>
</Basicform>
```

Comment: `UploadFile` requires that you send a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data` and an `input type="file"` field. Since you haven't included what `create` does, I'm guessing that it submits the content as JSON and not as a multipart form post. If you want to submit a JSON body (as is common from a Javascript application such as react), you can instead use a pydantic model that matches your JSON strucuture and encode the file data as base64 data, which you deserialize on the server side.

Comment: You would need to send the file data as `FormData`, using the key defined in your endpoint, i.e., `file`, and the file object obtained from an [`<input type="file">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) element. For instance, `var formData = new FormData(); formData.append("file", fileInput.files[0]);`. Please have a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70824288/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72029319/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804), for more details.

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue by trying to create python pop request for  [FastAPI demo file upload](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/). Working from `docs` where it gave me ready code in form of curl line:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploadfile/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@test_file'
```

(FastAPI auto generated docs page).
Which i used as hint and from which I got that header for file name should be in the form of `"type" : "multipart/form-data" , files = { "file" : test_file_descriptor  }` And it worked

More exact: key for the file descriptor should be `file`. My case (Python):
`test_response = requests.post(test_url, data={'filename': test_file , "msg":"hello" ,"type" : "multipart/form-data"}, files = { "file" : test_file  } )` Where `test_file` is file descriptor.
I know that my case might be different, but this is the only meaningful google link for this error, and someone with my case could also use it.

Answer (score 0):

check the post request you are sending as it's case sensitive .swagger document post part and testing doc post request should match.

```
And request 
"""{
            "question": "#(question)",
            "History":{}
                   
    }"""    
When method post
```