# Cannot Upload File to FastAPI backend using JavaScript Fetch API in the frontend

Tags: javascript, python, multipartform-data, fastapi, fetch-api

I'm trying to figure out how to send an image to my API, and also verify a generated `token` that is in the `header` of the request.

So far this is where I'm at:

```py
@app.post("/endreProfilbilde")
async def endreProfilbilde(request: Request,file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    token=request.headers.get('token')
    print(token)
    print(file.filename)
```

I have another function that triggers the change listener and upload function, passing the parameter: `bildeFila`

```js
function lastOpp(bildeFila) {
            var myHeaders = new Headers(); 
            let data = new FormData();
            data.append('file',bildeFila)
            myHeaders.append('token', 'SOMEDATAHERE'); 
            myHeaders.append('Content-Type','image/*');
            let myInit = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: myHeaders,
                cache: 'default',
                body: data,
            };
            var myRequest = new Request('http://127.0.0.1:8000/endreProfilbilde', myInit); 
            fetch(myRequest)//more stuff here, but it's irrelevant for the Q
}
```

**The Problem**:
This will print the `filename` of the uploaded file, but the `token` isn't passed and is printed as `None`. I suspect this may be due to the `content-type`, or that I'm trying to force FastAPI to do something that is not meant to be doing.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#sending_files_using_a_formdata_object):

> **Warning**: When using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to submit `POST` requests using [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or the [`Fetch_API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) with the
> `multipart/form-data` Content-Type (e.g. when uploading [`Files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and
> [`Blobs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) to the server), **do not** explicitly set the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)
> header on the request. Doing so will prevent the browser from being
> able to set the `Content-Type` header with the `boundary` expression
> it will use to delimit form fields in the request body.

Hence, you should **remove** the `Content-Type` header from your code when sending the `fetch` request. The same applies to sending requests through [Python Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71146753/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641755/17865804). Read more about the [boundary in multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data).

**Working examples** on how to upload file(s) using FastAPI in the backend and Fetch API in the frontend can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73264904/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74507628/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689003/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74810115/17865804).

Comment: You are indeed correct, it simply either ignores it or throws and error, as I figured out. I'll be posting my working soluition shorly

Answer (score -1):

So I figured this one out thanks to a helpful lad in Python's Discord server.

```js
function lastOpp(bildeFila) {
            let data = new FormData();
            data.append('file',bildeFila)
            data.append('token','SOMETOKENINFO')
}
```

```py
@app.post("/endreProfilbilde")
async def endreProfilbilde(token: str = Form(...),file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print(file.filename)
    print(token)
```

Sending the string value as part of the formData rather than as a header lets me grab the parameter.