# How to display uploaded image in HTML page using FastAPI & Jinja2?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI & Jinja2 to serve an HTML page to upload an image file, and then open another HTML link with the uploaded image name to show that image. Even though I was able to get the uploading part and the uploaded image link working, I was unable to get the `src` tag to work to actually display the image. How could I solve that?

This is **main.py**:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile,Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles 
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
 """ upload file and save it to local """ 
@app.post("/upload-file")
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
with open(file.filename, "wb") as f:
    f.write(file.file.read())
return {"filename": file.filename}

''' create html page to show uploaded file '''
@app.get("/")
async def root():
html_content = """
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload File</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Upload File</h1>
        <form action="/upload-file/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
"""
return HTMLResponse(content=html_content)


templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


 @app.get("/{filename}", response_class=HTMLResponse)
 async def read_item(request: Request, filename: str):
   return templates.TemplateResponse("template.html", {"request":  request,"filename": filename})
```

and this is **template.html**:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML img Tag</title>
</head>

<body>
    <img src= "{{./filename}} " alt="uploaded image" width="400" height="400">
</body>
</html>
```

I'm open to better/simpler ways to achieve the needed results. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Download a File after POSTing data using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73234675/how-to-download-a-file-after-posting-data-using-fastapi)

Comment: Also, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71324775/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71193588/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689003/17865804) answer. Note: if what you want is to display the same image that the user has uploaded, you don't need to have FastAPI send it back to you, just use [`FileReader.readAsDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) (as shown in Option 2 of the last link above) that allows you to preview the img.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Preview Uploaded Image in the same HTML page

Here is an example of the suggested solution in the comments section (previously described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788970/how-to-send-a-base64-encoded-image-to-a-fastapi-backend/70689003#70689003)), where you can use [`FileReader.readAsDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) to convert the image to a base64 encoded string on client side and display the image on the page, without having FastAPI backend send it back to you, as you need to display the same (unprocessed) image uploaded by the user. For related solutions see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71324775/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71193588/17865804). Also, to use *asynchronous* writing for writing the image file to the disk, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65342833/fastapi-uploadfile-is-slow-compared-to-flask/70667530#70667530).

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import File, UploadFile, Request, FastAPI
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        contents = file.file.read()
        with open("uploaded_" + file.filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(contents)
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
    finally:
        file.file.close()
        
    return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {file.filename}"}

@app.get("/")
def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function previewFile() {
        const preview = document.querySelector('img');
        const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
            preview.src = reader.result; // show image in <img> tag
            uploadFile(file)
        }, false);
        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }

    function uploadFile(file) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        fetch('/upload', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
</script>
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

#### Upload Image with the Click of a Button

In case you need the image to be uploaded to the FastAPI server after the user has clicked on an `Upload Image` button—instead of being automatically uploaded as in the template above as soon as the user has chosen an image—as well as you would like to display the message from the server, whether the image has been succesfully uploaded or not, you can use the template below instead.

templates/**index.html**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function previewFile() {
        const preview = document.querySelector('img');
        var file = document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
            preview.src = reader.result; // show image in <img> tag
        }, false);
        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }

    function uploadFile(file) {
        var file = document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0];
        if (file) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file);
            fetch('/upload', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData,
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    document.getElementById("serverMsg").innerHTML = data.message;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="file" id="fileInput" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<input type="button" value="Upload Image" onclick="uploadFile()">
<p id="serverMsg"></p>
<img height="200">
```

#### Preview Image in a New Tab

To preview the image in a new tab instead of the same tab, you can use the following. The below will open the image in a new tab (using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27798235)) once the user has clicked on the `"Upload Image"` button. If you need the tab to open when the user has chosen an image instead, then comment out the `previewFile()` line in the `uploadFile()` function and uncomment the commented HTML `<input type="file">` element, where `onchange="previewFile()"` is used.

templates/**index.html**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function previewFile() {
       const preview = document.querySelector('img');
       var file = document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0];
       const reader = new FileReader();
       reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
          displayImgInNewTab(reader.result)
       }, false);
       if (file) {
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       }
    }

    function uploadFile() {
       var file = document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0];
       if (file) {
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file', file);
          fetch('/upload', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
             })
             .then(response => response.json())
             .then(data => {
                document.getElementById("serverMsg").innerHTML = data.message;
             })
             .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
             });
          previewFile()
       }
    }

    function displayImgInNewTab(data) {
       var image = new Image();
       image.src = data
       var w = window.open("");
       w.document.write(image.outerHTML);
    }
</script>
<!--<input type="file" id="fileInput" onchange="previewFile()"><br>-->
<input type="file" id="fileInput"><br>
<input type="button" value="Upload Image" onclick="uploadFile()">
<p id="serverMsg"></p>
<img height="200">
```

## Return and Display Uploaded Image in a new Jinja2 Template

If what you want is to display the uploaded image in a new Jinja2 template, you can then convert the image to a base64-encoded string and return it using a [`TemplateResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/#using-jinja2templates), where you can display it. Working example is given below. Alternatively, you could save the uploaded image under a [`StaticFiles`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/) directory and display it to the user in a new template [using the `url_for()` function](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/#templates-and-static-files) (e.g., `{{ url_for('static', path='/uploaded_img.png') }}`); however—as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804), which demonstrates two further approaches for displaying/downloading a file returned from the server—you need to consider whether you expect your server to serve more than one user, and whether users should be able to view/access other users' uploaded images or not, as well as you may need to consider generating random names/UUIDs for the filenames (as users may upload images having the same `filename`), and having a mechanism to delete the images from disk, when not needed anymore (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804)). In that case, the approach demonstrated below might be a better choice for you.

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import File, UploadFile, Request, FastAPI
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import base64

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get("/")
def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
  
@app.post("/upload")
def upload(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        contents = file.file.read()
        with open("uploaded_" + file.filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(contents)
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
    finally:
        file.file.close()
        
    base64_encoded_image = base64.b64encode(contents).decode("utf-8")

    return templates.TemplateResponse("display.html", {"request": request,  "myImage": base64_encoded_image})
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <form method="post" action="/upload"  enctype="multipart/form-data">   
         <label for="file">Choose image to upload</label>
         <input type="file" id="files" name="file"><br> 
         <input type="submit" value="Upload">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

templates/**display.html**

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Display Uploaded Image</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>My Image<h1>
      <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ myImage | safe }}">
   </body>
</html>
```

An alternative to the above approach would be to use a [`StaticFiles`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/) directory, where you can save the image uploaded by the user, and then return a [`TemplateResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/#using-jinja2templates), passing the path to that image as one of the key-value pairs in the Jinja2 "context" (e.g., `'imgPath': /static/uploaded_img.png'`), which you can use to display the image in the `Jinja2Template`, e.g., `<img src="{{ imgPath }}">`. **Note:** Using this approach, images saved under `/static` directory would be accessible to anyone using the system. Hence, if this is an issue for your task, it might be better not to follow this approach. Also, using this approach, you might need—depending on the requirements of your project—to set up some process to delete the images after some limited period, in order to prevent running out of disk space. Further approaches for returning a file/image can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73414443/17865804).

Comment: Thanks for the example provided Chris , while it actually does show the uploaded image , It is important to my use is to be able preview image in separate html page. I will try to create another template and include the preview part of the script .

Comment: I was able to make it work , and I used the revised code you provided " much better code than mine " , I accept your solution and marked it as answer . Thank you Chris.

Comment: If you had to define the `/upload` endpoint with `async def` - as you might need to `await` for some other coroutines - please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) on how to use `async` writing with `aiofiles`. I would also suggest you have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details on `def` vs `async def`.