# How to upload a csv file using Jinja2 Templates and FastAPI , and return it after modifications?

Tags: python, html, csv, jinja2, fastapi

I am using FastAPI to upload a csv file, perform some modifications on it and then return it to the HTML page. I am using Jinja2 as the template engine and HTML in frontend.

How can I upload the csv file using Jinja2 template, modify it and then return it to the client?

### Python code

```py
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Request
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get("/")
def form_post(request: Request):
result = "upload file"
return templates.TemplateResponse('home.html', context={'request': request, 'result': result})

@app.post("/")
def upload(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...)):

    contents1 = file.file.read()
    buffer1 = BytesIO(contents1)
    test1 = pd.read_csv(buffer1)
    buffer1.close()
    file.file.close()
    test1 = dict(test1.values)
    
    return templates.TemplateResponse('home.html', context={'request': request, 'result': test1})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

### HTML code

```html
\<!DOCTYPE html\>
\<html lang="en"\>
\<head\>
\<meta charset="UTF-8"\>
\<title\>RUL_PREDICTION\</title\>
\</head\>
\<body\>
\<h1\>RUL PREDICTION\</h1\>
\<form method="post"\>
\<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/\>
\<button type="submit"\>upload\</button\>
\</form\>
\<p\>{{ result }}\</p\>
\</body\>
\</html\>
```

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work? What happens that shouldn't happen? What result did you expect? Is that how your HTML file look, or has something gone wrong with escaping?

Comment: when i upload the csv file using the html in frontend and press the upload button , i am getting the below error.

Comment: {
"detail": [
{
"loc": [
"body",
"file"
],
"msg": "Expected UploadFile, received: <class 'str'>",
"type": "value_error"
}
]
}

Comment: If you're going to upload files through a form you need to set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form-element: `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74317758/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804). You may also find helpful posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205127/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655118/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71478057/17865804).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working example below is derived from the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74317758/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655118/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71478057/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804), at which I would suggest you have a look for more details and explanation.

##### Sample data

**data.csv**

```
Id,name,age,height,weight
1,Alice,20,62,120.6
2,Freddie,21,74,190.6
3,Bob,17,68,120.0
```

## Option 1 - Return modified data in a new CSV file

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Request, Response, HTTPException
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')

@app.post('/upload')
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        contents = file.file.read()
        buffer = BytesIO(contents) 
        df = pd.read_csv(buffer)
    except:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Something went wrong')
    finally:
        buffer.close()
        file.file.close()

    # remove a column from the DataFrame
    df.drop('age', axis=1, inplace=True)
    
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="modified_data.csv"'}
    return Response(df.to_csv(), headers=headers, media_type='text/csv')
    

@app.get('/')
def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {'request': request})
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="post" action="/upload"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <label for="csvFile">Choose a CSV file</label>
         <input type="file" id="csvFile" name="file" onchange="enableSubmitBtn();"><br><br>
         <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="submit" disabled>
      </form>
      <script>
         function enableSubmitBtn() {
            document.getElementById('submitBtn').removeAttribute("disabled");
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

## Option 2 - Return modified data in a new Jinja2 Template

If you would rather like to return a new Jinja2 template with the modified data instead of a csv file as demonstrated above, you could use the below.

##### Method 1

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) to render the DataFrame as an HTML table. You could optionally use the `classes` parameter in `to_html()` function to pass a `class` name, or a list of names, that will be used in a style sheet in your frontend to style the table. Additionally, you could remove the `border` by specifying `border=0` in `to_html()`.

**app.py**

```py
# ... (rest of code is same as in Option 1)

@app.post('/upload')
def upload(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    # ... (rest of code is same as in Option 1)

    context = {'request': request, 'table': df.to_html()}
    return templates.TemplateResponse('results.html', context)
```

templates/**results.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>{{ table | safe }}</body>
</html>
```

##### Method 2

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to convert the DataFrame to a dictionary and return it.

**app.py**

```py
# ... (rest of code is same as in Option 1)

@app.post('/upload')
def upload(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    # ... (rest of code is same as in Option 1)

    context = {'request': request, 'data': df.to_dict(orient='records'), 'columns': df.columns.values}
    return templates.TemplateResponse('results.html', context)
```

templates/**results.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <table style="width:50%">
            <tr>
                {% for c in columns %}<td>{{ c }}</td>{% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% for d in data %}
                <tr>
                    {% for v in d.values() %}
                        <td>{{ v }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <br>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
@app.post("/")
def upload(file: UploadFile):

    with open("temp.csv", "wb") as f:
        for row in file.file:
            f.write(row)
    
    with open("temp.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as csv:
        # modifications
    

    return FileResponse(path="temp.csv", filename="new.csv", media_type="application/octet-stream")
```