# Returning Pandas DataFrame in FastAPI response model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fastapi

I am trying to return a Pandas DataFrame using FastAPI.

My response model looks something like:

```
class Response(BaseModel):
    df: Dict
    date: str
```

I then have my function run, which creates a Pandas data frame, and a date, which I am currently trying to return via:

```
return Response(
        df=df.to_dict(orient="records"),
        date=f"{df.index.mean():%Y-%m-%d}",
    )
```

However, when doing so I get the error:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for Response
df
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

I've tried changing the response model for `df` to be `str` and `json`, and wrapping the response with `json.dumps` and `jsonable_encoder`, but it never truly worked. If I give the `df` a `str` type in the `Response` model it actually somewhat worked. However, the formatting was not good at all.

I don't know if the easiest way is somewhat converting that "stringy" version of the `df` to something useful when I get it to the front-end, or if I'm just missing something simple to fix it from the back-end?

Comment: Please also have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74588435/17865804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), `df.to_dict(orient="records"` actually returns a list `[{column: value}, … , {column: value}]`. So changing your model to

```py
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel

class Response(BaseModel):
    df: list[dict[str, Any]]
    date: str
```

should do the trick.