# fetch fastapi post request

Tags: javascript, fetch, fastapi

Javascript code:

```
 const submitHandler = async (e) => {
 
     const user = document.getElementById("email").value;

     await fetch('https://clownfish-app-fqu4k.ondigitalocean.app/meadow', {
         method: "POST",
         headers: "content-type": "application/json",
         body: user,
      })

   }
```

Python:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


class User(BaseModel):
    email: str


@app.post("/meadow")
def password_validation(user: User):
    return {
        "status": "success",
        "data": user
    }
```

The above works fine in Postman, but in Chrome gives the following error:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

I've updated the code to include the suggestions below. No joy. The request results in a 422 error - an "Unprocessable Entity". Should I be using the FormData class as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62798421/how-to-send-file-to-fastapi-endpoint-using-postman#comment111071496_62798421) answer?
I've also tried setting the fetch headers to 'accept'.

**UPDATE**
My request is resulting in a

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"value is not a valid dict","type":"type_error.dict"}]}
```

so I'm not sending the data in the way Pydantic is expecting it

**UPDATE 2**
Novice mistake - I wasn't stringifying the data before sending it. See @Quentin's answer below.

Comment: Look up. It probably tells you why on the line above the two you screenshotted. Odds are either a 500 error or a CORS error (or both!)

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] though. Your code defines `email`, but doesn't use it, and uses `user` but never defines it.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo - I've amended it

Comment: Does your server side code expect a plain text request body? Normally URL Encoded, JSON, or Form Multipart is expected.

Comment: What does the console say before the generic *Failed to fetch* error?

Comment: @Quentin - Hey Quentin, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`user` is whatever string the user typed in.

> ```
> const user = document.getElementById("email").value;
> ```

---

And you are putting that string into the body, completely raw, and claiming that it is JSON.

> ```
>     headers: "content-type": "application/json",
>     body: user,
> ```

---

It seems unlikely that the user is typing JSON into the email field.

If you tell the server you are sending JSON, then you need to actually send JSON.

While I'm not remotely familiar with FastAPI, it looks like the JSON text that is expected is:

```
{ "email": "some value" }
```

So you need to construct that:

```
body: JSON.stringify({ email: user })
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks champ - very much appreciate your time.

Answer (score -1):

Try this on your server.

Your code doesn't have CORS enabled. You need to enable it, if you are using a cross domain request.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

class User(BaseModel):
    email: str


@app.post("/meadow")
def password_validation(user: User):
    return {
        "status": "success",
        "data": user
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've tried this but I'm still not getting a response from the server